# jQuery - how to navigate around a table and remove an attribute,

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table in which a row is set to a certain background color if an Ajax call has succeeded. I need to be able to clear background colour on the next Ajax operation, so only the last row updated has it's background set. Example table row with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.update-allocation').click(function(event) {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var desc = $row.find('input[name="item.Description"]').val();
    var gift = $row.find('input[name="item.GiftAidable"]').is(':checked');
    var isActive = $row.find('input[name="item.IsActive"]').is(':checked');

    $row.closest('table').children('td').removeAttr("background-color")
    $row.parent().find('td').removeAttr("background-color")

    $row.children().css({
      "background-color": "green"
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="item_AllocationId" name="item.AllocationId" type="hidden" value="3">
      <input class="form-control input-width-medium text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="item_Description" name="item.Description" type="text" value="Donation Box">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-item_GiftAidable"><span class="checked"><input checked="checked" class="uniform checkbox" id="item_GiftAidable" name="item.GiftAidable" type="checkbox" value="true"></span>

      </div>
      <input name="item.GiftAidable" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-isActive"><span class="checked"><input checked="checked" class="uniform checkbox" id="isActive" name="item.IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true"></span>

      </div>
      <input name="item.IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="update-allocation" type="submit" name="update-allocation" value="Update" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And fiddle here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owoze110/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.update-allocation').click(function (event) {
        var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
        var desc = $row.find('input[name="item.Description"]').val();
        var gift = $row.find('input[name="item.GiftAidable"]').is(':checked');
        var isActive = $row.find('input[name="item.IsActive"]').is(':checked');

        $row.closest('table').find('td').css({'background-color': 'inherit'})

        $row.children().css({"background-color":"green"});
        //alert('description: ' + desc + '\ngift aidable: ' + gift + '\nis active: '+isActive);
    });
});
```

Should do the trick

https://jsfiddle.net/owoze110/8/

The I would recommend using classes for this job.

Add the class to the active row and use css rules to set the `background-color`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Also prefer the idea of using inherit :)

Answer (score 1):

you are applying background-color as style and removing as attribute so it wont works instead u should remove attribute of style

```
$row.closest('table').find('td').removeAttr( "style" );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hn2paLkd/)